# Installing cryptography 2.2.1 or higher from wheel

Tags: python

I am trying to install cryptography 2.2.1 or higher from a wheel. Pip is no longer able to connect to the pypi site due to an SSL error. The suggestion is to upgrade python. But the software I am supporting (ArcGIS 10.2.1) uses python 2.7.5. So, cannot change python versions. Therefore, I have been using downloaded wheel files for my installs. But I can not get cryptography to install.

Pip:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement enum34; python_version < "3"

It looks like pip is looking for a version of python that is less than 3. Suggestions?

Comment: The issue here is that it needs `enum34`. You can grab that, install it manually, and then see if you've satisfied the deps. The current deps for cryptography 2.4.2 are the sum of https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/704fe0fcaf206462b6a994ab69ad302601d9fad3/setup.py#L296 and https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/704fe0fcaf206462b6a994ab69ad302601d9fad3/setup.py#L290-L292. The first link is just deps required if not running on Python 3.

Comment: oh... I was thinking it was an enumerated list, not a package. hahaha... well, I feel silly now. Thanks for the help! I will do as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

check the wheel file you are using according to your system as both cryptography and enum64 supports 2.7 .